# DjangoREST APIView - different url params for different methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got a DjangoREST APIView that supports Read and Create operations. Something like this:

```
class FirebaseUser(APIView):
  ...
  get(request):
    ...
   
  post(request):
    ...
```

urls.py:

```
...
path('user/', views.FirebaseUser.as_view()),
...
```

I need an API that would accept a read request with user id as url param

`GET .../api/user/<userId>`

But for create operation there's no user ID yet and I need something like this

`POST .../api/user/`

What is the best way to make my APIView treat url params differently depending on method?

Comment: you can easily declare one more path in your urls.py, to support `GET /api/user/<userId>`. Then in your `FirebaseUser.get()` method, you can access that user_id using `self.params['userId']` or `self.query_params['userId']` or `self.request.GET.get('userId')` (at least one of them will work).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `ModelViewSet` like this in your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class FirebaseUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FirebaseUser.objects.all() # or whatever should your queryset be
    serializer_class = FirebaseUserSerializer
```

Then, in your `urls.py` you register the viewset:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', FirebaseUserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This will create a few new API endpoints and you'll be able to do all the CRUD operations.

I suggest reading a bit more about `ModelViewSets` in the [official docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

Also, if you require only certain operations, for example only `read` and `create` you may consider extending only certain mixins from `rest_framework.mixins` (read more [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins)).

Comment: The point is that I wasn't able to use ModelViewSet since I didn't work with my my own DB but kinda redirected requests to Firestore... But ViewSet did the trick

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with using ViewSet instead of APIView.
This is how it looks now:
urls.py

```
    path('user/', views.FirebaseUser.as_view({'post': 'create'})),
    path('user/<str:pk>', views.FirebaseUser.as_view({'patch': 'update', 'delete': 'destroy'})),
```

views.py

```
class FirebaseUser(ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [...]
    permission_classes = [...]

    @staticmethod
    def create(request):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def update(request: Request, pk=None):
        uid = pk
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def destroy(request: Request, pk=None):
        uid = pk
        ...
```